# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

we wanna add an event "onPress" but the function doesn't work. the Back-end is working (with postman) but we have a 404 error with the fetch the bundle sayed : [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']

The code :

```
renderMesClubs = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            const data = {choixClub: JSON.stringify(element.nomClub)};

            const headers = new Headers({
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
            });

            const options = {
              method: 'POST',
              body: data,
              headers: headers,
            };

            fetch('http://localhost:8080/inscription/choixclub', options)
              .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
              })
              .then(
                (responseData) => {
                  this.setState({message: responseData.message});
                },
                (err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                },
              );
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(209,209,209, .4)',
              borderRadius: 20,
              margin: 20,
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                textAlign: 'center',
                marginTop: 30,
                fontSize: 18,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba (209,209,209, .4)',
              }}>
              {element.nomClub}
            </Text>
            <Image
              style={styles.tinyLogo}
              source={{uri: 'http://localhost:8080/' + element.logo}}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  };
```

Thank you a lot for your precious help !!!

Comment: Can you paste the response from backend here? Or paste it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and check if it's valid JSON

Comment: have u tried console logging the responseData? console log it if its an object or something then JSON.stringify() it

Comment: Your response contains some kind of XML, perhaps HTML.

Comment: @domenikk also the back
```
 choixClub: (req, res) => {
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: "5f3689d4e86c8e3c1c026751" },
      {
        $set: {
          club: req.body.clubChoix,
        },
      },

      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json({ message: "une erreur s'est produite" });
        } else {
          res.json({
            message: " Votre club de coeur a bien été enregistré ",
          });
        }
      }
    );
  },
};
```

Comment: @WendyMontagnon Is that the response? If so, it's not valid JSON. You need to check your backend code

Comment: @WendyMontagnon I meant the response you see in Network Requests. The backend code seems fine

Comment: @domenikk the response is only the good one with "postman"  but with the front the only response (even with the console.log) is JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' react native.

Comment: Can you paste the one you get from Postman?

Comment: the response in postman for the body is {
    "message": " Votre club de coeur a bien été enregistré "
}

Comment: That's strange. Can you console.log(response) before transforming it (return response.json)? Also, could you try removing the special characters in backend (é for example)?

Comment: @domenikk the answer : {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "D2B82505-E5C5-4D7B-8327-408D054BEE94", "name": "choixclub.html", "offset": 0, "size": 161, "type": "text/html"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "D2B82505-E5C5-4D7B-8327-408D054BEE94", "name": "choixclub.html", "offset": 0, "size": 161, "type": "text/html"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"connection": "keep-alive", "content-length": "161", "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self'",

Comment: "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 27 Aug 2020 12:02:29 GMT", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-powered-by": "Express"}}, "ok": false, "status": 404, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "http://localhost:8080/inscription/choixclub"}

Comment: You need to manage the 404 before transforming to JSON, apparently your backend isn't returning valid JSON in this case. I'll post an answer so it can be seen better

Answer (score 1):

The backend is not returning valid JSON on a 404.
You need to handle that case:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/inscription/choixclub", options)
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.status === 404) throw new Error('Resource not found');

    return response.json();
  })
  .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({ message: responseData.message });
    }
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    // TODO: manage not found error
  });
```

Also try passing headers like this:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

Comment: Thanks guys i found a solution i have to add  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

got this error when i send non object data.
i was supposed to send `{email: xyz@gmail.com}` but i was sending `xyz@gmail.com`